# file.length return always 0 in android

Tags: android, file

I want to check size of file where I have only URI `content://media/external/video/media/813`
to get size of file I use:

```
File file=new File(uri.getPath());
                    long ls = file.length();
```

and always get 0. Any ideas?

Comment: i guess it's a directory

Comment: file.length() will return zero if file not exists

Comment: @AvinashRoy looking at the `URI`, I don't think it's a directory.

Comment: God knows what it is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

File file = new File(filePath);
long ls = file.length();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try below code to get length of your file

```
 Cursor returnCursor =
                getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        int size = (int) returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex);
```

Comment: for those who want to get size in KB & MB : `int sizeKB = size / 1024; int sizeMb = size / (1024 * 1024)`